# Listbox custom property

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I'm building a web app that will have 100's (maybe 1000+) items that I need to display in a ListBox-style control. However, I need to hold more than just `text` and `value` data for each item. 
I've tried using a repeater with a table in the itemtemplate which works and displays the way I want it to but it has poor performance.

The data is coming from an SQL Datasource.

Is there a way to customize the ListBox control to allow more than one value per list item?

Comment: If you want those custom property at client side i.e. javascript only, then you can add those to listitem as attribute, I can help you on, let me know if that is your requirement? But if you want to change those custom property and access in serverside, that might not be feasible.

Comment: It needs to be serverside unfortunately. All the information is coming from SQL and there is also a postback to update the SQL table so I dont think js will cut it

Comment: Ok, idea is to set those custom value to `listitem` and if any change to those value happen via JS, you can store same thing to a hidden field on page postback get those value from hidden field and re-save to DB>

Answer (score 0):

let me explain it with step by step

First you need a multiple selection enable listbox for that you have to use your listbox like

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Height="149px" SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="113px">
```

then you want to perform Opration on ListboxItem for that you have to perform operation like

```
 private void UpClick()
{
    // only if the first item isn't the current one
    if(listBox1.ListIndex > 0)
    {
        // add a duplicate item up in the listbox
        listBox1.AddItem(listBox1.Text, listBox1.ListIndex - 1);
        // make it the current item
        listBox1.ListIndex = (listBox1.ListIndex - 2);
        // delete the old occurrence of this item
        listBox1.RemoveItem(listBox1.ListIndex + 2);
    }
}



 private void DownClick()
{
   // only if the last item isn't the current one
   if((listBox1.ListIndex != -1) && (listBox1.ListIndex < listBox1.ListCount - 1))
   {
      // add a duplicate item down in the listbox
      listBox1.AddItem(listBox1.Text, listBox1.ListIndex + 2);
      // make it the current item
      listBox1.ListIndex = listBox1.ListIndex + 2;
      // delete the old occurrence of this item
      listBox1.RemoveItem(listBox1.ListIndex - 2);
   }
}
```

for Select All you can clear the Listbox2 and fill all Items from Listbox1 to Listbox2.

Comment: Ty, I did mention however that moving items from one box to the other isn't the question....